# How to use AJAXControlToolkit’s Modelpopu with ConfirmDialog?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to use AJAXControlToolkit’s Modelpopu with ConfirmDialog.I am using VS2008. Following is my code

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="btnSave_Click" />
<asp:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="btnSave_ConfirmButtonExtender" runat="server" 
         ConfirmText="Want to Save?" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="btnSave">
</asp:ConfirmButtonExtender>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="btnSave_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" 
          DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="btnSave">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Please guide me what should I do to make it run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the AJAX Control Toolkit documentation for the ConfirmButtonExtender:
http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.aspx

> - **DisplayModalPopupID** - Optionally specifies the ID of a ModalPopup control to use for displaying the confirmation dialog (instead of window.confirm). When using DisplayModalPopupID, the following conditions must be met:
>
>   - The ModalPopup must be configured to work against the same TargetControlID as the ConfirmButton (and should work properly if the ConfirmButton is disabled).
>   - The ModalPopup must specify OkControlID and/or CancelControlID to identify the buttons corresponding to window.confirm's OK/Cancel buttons.
>   - The ModalPopup must not specify OnOkScript or OnCancelScript.

Example of using the AJAX controls together in your page:

```
<asp:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="btnSave_ConfirmButtonExtender" runat="server"
    ConfirmText="Want to Save?" TargetControlID="btnSave" 
    DisplayModalPopupID="btnSave_ModalPopupExtender"></asp:ConfirmButtonExtender>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="btnSave_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="btnSave" PopupControlID="Panel1"
    OkControlID="btnOK" CancelControlID="btnCancel"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Where Panel1 is an `<asp:Panel>` that gets displayed as the modal dialog, and `btnOK` and `btnCancel` are the OK and Cancel buttons on that panel.

Comment: can you make sample changes in code (given by me above) to make thing clear.